# PHP - Google Drive API HTTP Response

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I'am making some script for download my file in google drive.

here my test.php

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
$drive = new Google_Client();
$drive->setClientId('709390325823-6bljk00f39xxxxx6jg3ji.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$drive->setClientSecret('UL07mxxxxx01eA'); 
$drive->setRedirectUri('http://xxx');
$drive->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
$drive->setAccessType('offline');
$gdrive = new Google_DriveService($drive);
$url = $drive->createAuthUrl();
 $token = $drive->authenticate($authorizationCode);
$fileId = "0B9LPSEw89uQNQVNuUzdwM2hFMlk";
$file = $gdrive->files->get($fileId);
      $downloadUrl = $file->downloadUrl;

 if ($downloadUrl) {
 $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
$io = $drive->getIo();
 $httpRequest = $io->makeRequest($request);
 if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
 return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
} else {

 error_log("Error Downloading Attachment - HTTP ResponseCode:".$httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode());
error_log("ContentUrl:         ".$attachment->getContentUrl());
error_log("ContentUrl:         ".$attachment->getContentUrl());
error_log("ContentType:        ".$attachment->getContentType());
error_log("id                  ".$attachment->getId());
error_log("IsProcessing:       ".(int)$attachment->getIsProcessingContent());
  return null;
}

 } else {
// An error occurred.
}
```

everything looks fine when i run with out downloadUrl, it show downloadUrl and token

> https://doc-0g-1s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/qjrgdcogjm0ajgdp4fnjceh8pfg486sg/u39dld0fisj9v0b3ih1nmchqp4495gdl/1473127200000/02390580194345273532/02390580194345273532/0B9LPSEw89uQNQVNuUzdwM2hFMlk?e=download&gd=true&access_token=ya29.Ci9WAxf99iwravP2CMmXEaYJWZb-1Y2Dxze1HToAyLb0_JJGrdVjFA5goQVBVRmWKg

but it show error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getResponseHttpCode() on a non-object in

what function http response in api google v2? Am I wrong to call function or something missing?

Hope you guys give some advice. thanks

Comment: I Don't think makerequest() returns anything...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the sample codes on how the [PHP client library](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/downloads) implementation is done.

Here is a sample code from the document that download Google Documents (Documents, Spreadsheets, Presentations, etc.) and export them to formats that your app can handle.

[*Google Drive v2*](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads):

```
/**
* Download a file's content.
*
* @param Google_Servie_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
* @param Google_Servie_Drive_DriveFile $file Drive File instance.
* @return String The file's content if successful, null otherwise.
*/
function downloadFile($service, $file) {
$downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
if ($downloadUrl) {
$request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
$httpRequest = $service->getClient()>getAuth()>authenticatedRequest($request);
if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
} else {
// An error occurred.
return null;
}
} else {
// The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
return null;
}
}
```

Here is a sample code from the document.

[*Google Drive v3*](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads).

```
$fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
$content = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array(
'alt' => 'media' ));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, @mr.Rebot, it shown error like this `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 132649397 bytes)` I heard about partial download, it possible to use it on my script?

Comment: why it show `Class 'Google_Http_Request' not found in /home/layarsinema/public_html/test.php on line 37`